# How to modify a responsebody compressed with an unsupported algorithm with fiddler

Tags: fiddler

I want to modify the responsebody.
However, the data is compressed by Brotli, which fiddler does not support.
I want to set a response breakpoint.
When fiddler break on the response.
I decompress the data with a tool, modify it and compress the modified data.
Copy the modified data to the fiddlerscript and save the fiddlerscript.

But I find that the response breakpoint breaks after the response arrived.
So when I resave the fiddlerscript, the script won't work on the breaked response.

How can I modify a responsebody compressed with an unsupported algorithm?

Comment: FWIW, while installing Brotli support is the way to go, for truly unsupported compression types, you'd just reload the newly modified content using the HexView response inspector or via the "Choose a file..." dropdown on the breakpoint bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install the Compressibility add on from http://www.telerik.com/fiddler/add-ons. This adds Brotly support to Fiddler at present.